# Loop through Facebook Comments in R with getPost

Tags: r, facebook, loops

I would like to consult on doing loop for getting comments on Facebook (Without knowing the number of posts) and combining all the data together using R.

I only manage to do it manually:

```
library(Rfacebook)
subset_data <- subset (page, grepl("Sports", page$message)
test1 <- getPost(post=page$id[1], token = myaccesstoken, comments = TRUE, likes = FALSE)
write.csv(test1, file = "test1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
test2 <- getPost(post=page$id[2], token = myaccesstoken, comments = TRUE, likes = FALSE)
write.csv(test2, file = "test2.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

I did manually for like more than 20 posts. 
And after which I would combine all the csv files together into 1 file.

I also would like to seek advice on excluding posts that do not have comments.

Thank you.

Below is the output result post in R that has no comments:

```
$post
       from_id    from_name
1 147054757571 Sports World

$message
1 Currently is showing the sport of badminton.\n\nFull story: http://sports.com

              created_time type
1 2015-08-24T17:23:11+0000 link

                              id likes_count comments_count shares_count
1 147054757571_10163515218373572          19              2            4

$comments
[1] from_id      from_name    message      created_time likes_count  id          
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize a list, and then loop through the length of your `page$id`s and create an if statement that writes the `csv` files only if the comments section contains at least one row of data.

```
test <- list()
for (i in 1:length(page$id)){
  test[[i]] <- getPost(post=page$id[i], token = myaccesstoken, comments = TRUE, likes = FALSE)
  if (nrow(test[[i]][["comments"]]) > 0) {
  write.csv(test[[i]], file = paste0("test", i, ".csv"), row.names = F)
  }
}
test.all <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, test)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I got this error: "error in function(..., deparse level = 1, make.row.names = TRUE) : invalid list argument: all variables should have the same length" when running the last line. @r3robertson

Comment: If the structure of the individual data.frames created in the for loop varies then you're going to have to shape them before combining them (which is what the last line should do if they all had the same structure). Hard to help you any further unless you provide some sample data. See `dput` for a good way to share your data.

Comment: It works actually, just that because some of the posts do not have message, therefore they cannot be written into csv file, hence errors occurred. May I consult on writing function to exclude those posts that do not have comments, and write into csv files on the posts that have comments only? Thank you. @r3robertson

Comment: I've added an `if` statement to my answer that should print only cases where comments are not equal to `NULL`. If you could post some sample data that would help me help you faster.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response, I tried your updated code, but still cant work. I have posted the output result that the post has no comment. Hope this helps. Thank you. @r3robertson

Comment: Based on the output I see I edited my `if` statement. You really need to learn how to use `dput`. If you use `dput(test1)` and paste the results I will be able to see the structure of your data and test my solutions instead of guessing at the problem. This is a standard practice on StackOverflow.